# Android View's Position on Gridlayout

Tags: android, resize, android-edittext, grid-layout

I placed EditText, TextView, ImageView in a GridLayout.
(My goal is to make an app like an Image Editor or OpenOffice Draw)

When I type a long text in EditText, its size is growing as I type characters.

As its size is growing, the other objects such as TextView and ImageView,
are moving to the right to make a room for EditText in the left.

I thought GridLayout was like a layout which can set absolute position.

Can I keep absolute position for other View object in GridLayout while one's size is changing?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Post your xml here please

Comment: Try to set EditText property `android:singleLine="true"` and then check.

Answer (score 0):

A normal thing occurs to EditText widgets whenever a very long text is entered.

What happens is that the width of the **EditText** gets resized even if you place `android:layout_width=”wrap_content”.`

But do not fret. There is a way to go around this.

Use the attributes

```
     `android:layout_width=”0dp”` `andandroid:layout_weight=”1″`.
```

It also helps (but not necessary) if you ensure that the **EditText** is only a one-liner by adding `android:singleLine=”true”`.